# TFS 2013: Custom TreePath Fields

Tags: tfs

according to this Thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d566e2e5-3782-4e2b-be3b-85228f41dfc3/add-a-tree-path-field-in-work-item it is not possible to create a TreePath or AreaPath for a custom-field.

I kinda can't believe nobody is running into extreme problems without this crucial controls. 
Since the last answer in this Thread (and the others about this I found) is from earlier last year, was there anything changed about this control?

Has anyone found a solution about this? I tried to google about creating own custom controls, but I think this is not possible. Is there any workarround to create a easy tree-structure in a control?

Thanks and greetings

Matthias

Answer (score 2):

Read more carefully. You cannot have *fields* with TreePath data type, but you can create custom controls for other data types.

In other words, you can create custom controls that display hierarchical information as long as you are able to represent this in an existing data type, in practice the String type.

Examples of custom controls at https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look into it. Do you know how smooth custom controls are working with TFS? 
The second need would be: Can I create a Query like "Under this node" like it is possible in the Iteration?

Comment: Smooth is vague term. Like every customization is has a price, these make upgrades more complex for example.

For the other topic, please post another SO question.