# TFS 2013: work item customization: need TreePath functionality for custom field

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

I am trying to customize a work item template and need to add a field which can capture hierarchical data.I am using TFS power tools to edit work items. I tried to create a new field with datatype as TreePath but when I save it, it throws an error: 
TF26179 – Field Type 'TreePath' can be used only with System.AreaPath & System.IterationPath

Is there any workaround to use the TreePath control for custom fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be duplicated with this thread : [TFS 2013: Custom TreePath Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383184/tfs-2013-custom-treepath-fields).

Just as the error message mentioned the Field Type '`TreePath`' can be used only with `System.AreaPath` & `System.IterationPath`.

So, Tree Path is not supported for other fields for now, and there is a [user voice submitted](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3805542-allow-the-use-of-tree-path-field-in-user-custom-fi) to request the feature, you can vote it or submit a new user voice to suggest the feature.

For custom control, you can reference the source code of the [vsts-extension-color-control](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-color-control)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new field with TreePath data type, but you can create custom controls for other data types, so you can create custom controls that display hierarchical information as long as you are able to represent this in an existing data type, in practice the String type.

Examples of custom controls at https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/.

Comment: I looked at the link, I don't see any custom controls there that can display hierarchical information? Could you give more details if you have done it yourself?